# Custom UserControl - Design-Time support for control repainting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, visual-studio-2015

I have created my custom `UserControl` with some custom properties for it. For example:

```
[Description("Example Description"),Category("CustomSettings"),DefaultValue("Transmedicom")]
public string DatabaseAddress
{
    get; set;
}
```

Everything works fine. I can change `custom property` in code and in `design-time`.

What I'm looking for (and cannot find anything) now is: How could I repaint (reacreate) my `UserControl` in design-time when my custom property change in design-time.

Let's say when `DatabaseName` will be changed to `localhost` `UserControl` will add and display some Label on my UserControl. It's important to work in `Design-Time`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special there. You just have to set the text to `Label` inside the property setter. That should update the UI.

```
private string databaseAddress;
[Description("Example Description"), Category("CustomSettings"), DefaultValue("Transmedicom")]
public string DatabaseAddress
{
    get { return databaseAddress; }
    set 
    { 
        databaseAddress = value;
        yourLabel.Text = value;//Set value to Label or whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private string _databaseAddress = "localHost";
[Description("Example Description"), Category("CustomSettings"), DefaultValue("Transmedicom")]
public string DatabaseAddress
{
    get
    {
        return _databaseAddress;
    } 
    set 
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            _databaseAddress = value;
            lblAddress.Text = value;
            lblAddress.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both previous answers are correct.
 I just want to add that the user control can even react on resizing during design time, using the `Layout` event.